# Is there an async alternative to the file operations in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, file-io, async-await

I am using c# with .Net 4.5. So I can use the async/await feature of .Net 4.5/ However I don't find the async methods for `File.Copy`, `File.Move`, `Directory.GetFiles` etc in `System.IO`.

Comment: Why not simply doing that in a new thread?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do that.
Look to this example I have copied for you from msdn.

You can do that by using FileStream and CopyToAsync:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string StartDirectory = @"c:\Users\exampleuser\start";
            string EndDirectory = @"c:\Users\exampleuser\end";

            foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(StartDirectory))
            {
                using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(EndDirectory + filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
                    {
                        await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or by using StreamReader and StreamWriter objects to read and write the contents of a file asynchronously.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string UserDirectory = @"c:\Users\exampleuser\";

    using (StreamReader SourceReader = File.OpenText(UserDirectory + "BigFile.txt"))
    {
        using (StreamWriter DestinationWriter = File.CreateText(UserDirectory + "CopiedFile.txt"))
        {
            await CopyFilesAsync(SourceReader, DestinationWriter);
        }
    }
}

public async Task CopyFilesAsync(StreamReader Source, StreamWriter Destination) 
{ 
    char[] buffer = new char[0x1000]; 
    int numRead; 
    while ((numRead = await Source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) 
    {
        await Destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, numRead);
    } 
}
```

More info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

No, there are not `async` equivalents for `Copy`/`Move`/etc. You can build them yourself if necessary.

`GetFiles` is a bit different. There is an `EnumerateFiles` which is more responsive (but not actually `async`).

Answer (score 2):

For copying you could make use of `Stream.CopyToAsync` method. Rest all you can wrap calls to corresponding methods in `Task.Run`